# Grails Spring Security core - Custom user information?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, grails

I'm using spring security core for authentication in my web app, but I can't figure out how to get a custom information from my User class
here's my user class:

```
package core

import beans.Colaborador
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = 'username')
@ToString(includes = 'username', includeNames = true, includePackage = false)
class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    transient springSecurityService
    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    Colaborador colaborador

    Usuario(String username, String password) {
        this()
        this.username = username
        this.password = password
    }

    Set<Permissao> getAuthorities() {
        UsuarioPermissao.findAllByUsuario(this)*.permissao
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
        colaborador nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

The information I want to use is inside Colaborador object, but if I try to access it by using **sec:loggedInUserInfo** and had no success, I've read that I need to create a Custom UserDetailsService, but I couldn't find out how and where to create it, can someone give me a hand?

Thanks!

@Edit

I tried following the documentation and I create two classes

```
import beans.Colaborador
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority

class MyUserDetails extends GrailsUser {

    final Colaborador colaborador

    MyUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
                  boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
                  boolean accountNonLocked,
                  Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities,
                  long id, Colaborador colaborador) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities, id)
        this.colaborador = colaborador
    }
}
```

and

```
package core    
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUserDetailsService
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.NoStackUsernameNotFoundException
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException

class MyUserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService {
    static final List NO_ROLES = [new SimpleGrantedAuthority(SpringSecurityUtils.NO_ROLE)]

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return loadUserByUsername(username)
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true, noRollbackFor = [IllegalArgumentException, UsernameNotFoundException])
    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Usuario user = Usuario.findByUsername(username)
        if (!user) throw new NoStackUsernameNotFoundException()
        def roles = user.authorities
        def authorities = roles.collect {
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it.authority)
        }

        return new MyUserDetails(user.username, user.password, user.enabled,
                !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired,
                !user.accountLocked, authorities ?: NO_ROLES, user.id,
                user.colaborador)
    }
}
```

and when I login in my app I get this error:

```
2016-11-14 11:56:46,061 [http-bio-80-exec-4] ERROR authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
Message: Could not find matching constructor for: java.lang.Object(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.util.ArrayList, java.lang.Long)
```

Comment: You just want access User class informtion into another method or Class right ?

Comment: I want to access custom user information from another class or view, in this case, data from that Colaborador object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#userDetailsService) outlines (step by step) how to create a custom `UserDetailsService`. It will walk you through the process of creating it and registering it within your application.

Comment: I've tried it, and now I'm getting this error: `2016-11-14 11:56:46,061 [http-bio-80-exec-4] ERROR authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter  - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
Message: Could not find matching constructor for: java.lang.Object(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, java.util.ArrayList, java.lang.Long)` when I login in my app (I'll put edit my ask and add the new code)

Comment: Did you register your `UserDetailsService` in `resources.groovy`?

Comment: I did, this is my resources.groovy  `import core.MyUserDetailsService
beans = {
    userDetailsService(MyUserDetailsService)
}`

Comment: I would stop the application, run `grails clean` and see if that clears up the issue.

Comment: I cleaned it up, now I'm getting this error when I run my app Message: `Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: core.MyUserDetails`

Comment: My mistake* I've created domain classes for my userdetails, changing it, it worked just fine, thanks everyone!